# LTSP - thin client VS fat client - how does the root folder work?

Tags: chroot, ltsp

There is plenty of information on the internet including here, but I could not find a specific discussion on it. Any comment is appreciated. Sorry if it is a very rookie question.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and the LTSP server. I also use Virtual Box to emulate a diskless thin/fat client to test it.

For now, I understand that the LTSP creates chroot environment at `/opt/ltsp/i386/` (or `amd64`) of the server(host). Until now, I found that:

**For thin client** (common build option, no desktop installed), after my logging into LDM using server username and password, the root folder will be the actual root of the server.

However, if press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> into terminal with admin accound logged in, the root folder is the chroot, which is reasonable.

**For fat client** (`FAT_CLIENT_DESKTOPS="ubuntu-desktop"` in `/etc/ltsp/ltsp-build-client.conf`) as described in [this tutorial](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-create-ubuntu-1104-x64-ltsp-server-32bit-thin-clients) , the root folder will be the chroot environment (`/opt/ltsp/i386/` as mentioned above)

Of course, the interface is different, where thin client will be the gnome-core version as I installed on my ubuntu server, and fat client uses unity, although I guess it is the default settings.

So, my question is how fat client got into graphic interface with `chroot` environment? but thin version is straight server root? Or, can I change the root such as, make the fat client visit actual server root and `chroot` for thin client?

I asking because I saw some tutorial saying you can install desktop by apt-get in a thin client, so that should be a conversion to fat client? BUT I can not see how this would change the root folder mounting.

Thanks a lot!